# Meteor accounts-facebook broken on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, meteor, accounts

I have created a meteor app and added the accounts-facebook package. I can login to the site using {{loginButtons}} fine from chrome (on Linux locally and from another machine) - however, when I try and login via Android (on the same network), the facebook popup reports: HTTP 500 error.

My serverside js looks like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    try{
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
        service : "facebook"
    });
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service : "facebook",
        appId : xxxx,
        secret : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    });


    Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
        console.log('creating user');
        //Do create stuff here
        // We still want the default hook's 'profile' behavior.
        if (options.profile)
            user.profile = options.profile;
        return user;
    });

    }catch(err){
      console.log(err.message);
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: My Meteor app is working fine on all platforms, Android included. Guess you doing something else. Perhaps you have already logged into facebook and pre-authenticated the app on your desktop computer, but not on your phone. All 500 errors should basically mean something has gone wrong on the SERVER. So check your logs.